# Can I send images selected randomly from a list of variables in my bot?

Tags: python, random, discord.py

I'm trying to make a Python discord bot that tells jokes, and one of the jokes will have an image instead of letters. All of my string variables are in a list, which are picked randomly with the random function in Python, so I wanna figure out how to make it so the image is picked randomly from them.

Here's my list:

```
joke_list = [first, second, third, fourth, fifth, sixth, seventh, eighth, ninth, tenth, eleventh,twelvth, thirteenth, fourteenth, fifteenth, sixteenth, seventeenth, eighteenth, nineteenth, twentieth, twentyfirst, twentysecond, twentythird, twentyfourth, twentyfifth, twentysixth, twentyseventh, twentyeighth, twentyninth, thirtieth, thirtyone, thirtytwo, thirtythree, thirtyfour, thirtyfive]
```

And this

```
if message.content.startswith('tell me a joke'):
        await message.channel.send(random.choice(joke_list))
```

Comment: How will the image be stored?  `channel.send` only accepts text, doesn't it?

Answer (score 0):

In order to send an Image with *discord.py* you have to create a discord.py [File object](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html?highlight=send#discord.File) and store it in your *joke_list*. You'd have to [check](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/functions.html#isinstance) if the random choice is a *File object*. If that is the case, you have to specify the *File object* in `message.channel.send()` with `file=<File object>`.

```py
joke_list = [..., discord.File]

...


if message.content.startswith('tell me a joke'):
    choice = random.choice(joke_list)

    if choice.isinstance(discord.File):
        await message.channel.send(file=choice)
    else:
        await message.channel.send(choice)
```

You can create  a *File object* by opening a normal file and passing it to the `discord.File` class.

```py
with open("some_image.png", "rb") as raw_image:
    image = discord.File(raw_image)
```